# assign values to R data frame by trend

Tags: r, colors, mutate

I have a data frame with many columns and rows. There are 3 columns which are the row IDs (ID), the conditions (Pass) and the frequency values (freq).

Input

df

```
ID  Pass  freq
A    1    010
A    2    100
A    3    100
A    4    100
B    1    010
B    2    100
B    3    010
B    4    100
C    1    025
C    2    050
C    3    075
C    4    100
D    1    100
D    2    075
D    3    050
D    4    025
E    1    010
E    2    010
E    3    010
E    4    100
F    1    010
F    2    100
F    3    100
F    4    010
```

I would like to create a new column $col_mut which assigns colour codes based on the trend of the values in $freq in each $Pass. So for example the freq in A is going up immediately and it gets coloured in green but the freq in C gradually grows so it gets coloured in red.

Output:

```
ID  Pass  freq col_mut
A    1    010. #008000
A    2    100. #008000
A    3    100. #008000
A    4    100  #008000
B    1    010  #807a00
B    2    100. #807a00
B    3    010. #807a00
B    4    100. #807a00
C    1    025  #d61a33
C    2    050  #d61a33
C    3    075. #d61a33
C    4    100. #d61a33
D    1    100  #2e2eb8
D    2    075. #2e2eb8
D    3    050  #2e2eb8 
D    4    025  #2e2eb8
E    1    010  #d6811a
E    2    010. #d6811a
E    3    010. #d6811a
E    4    100. #d6811a
F    1    010. #b62eb8
F    2    100. #b62eb8
F    3    100. #b62eb8
F    4    010. #b62eb8
```

Any suggestion on how to approach this?
I would like to highlight that my real data frame has more then 4 rows for each ID and sometime some value are there in each Pass but sometimes no

Comment: You need to decide on a specific metric, maybe correlation, slope of a linear regression, maximum increase in one step... something that behaves like you want. Calculate that for each group, then assign the colors.

Comment: I took a look at the colors you assigned but it's unclear if there's a particular logic you want to use for assigning them. https://imgur.com/a/WOsme8s

Comment: if you could create the rules around the jumps for the red and green values, I can code it. Ultimately it's kinda arbitarary after how many consecutive values a red can change to a green, and vice versa, so please pick a number

Comment: also, are you wanting to go straight from red to green, with a reddy-green in the middle? or are you wanting an intermediate colour, like white?

Comment: if you could produce a table which shows the colours for each state between pure red (rgb 255, 0, 0) and pure green (0, 255, 0) that would be great!

Comment: also if you can clarify what you mean by "sometime some value are there in each Pass but sometimes no"

Comment: I have a working version for a red/green dichotomy but it doesn't really work well with the data you provided.

Comment: @JonSpring there is no specific logic, just that  the colours need to be visually different from each other to differentiate them